# Publish a collection from queried list of collections

Tags: meteor

I've been searching for a way to publish collections that are dynamic. The collections are structured in mongodb as below:

```
Parents collection {Children}
Child1 collection
Child2 collection
```

I want to publish the individual children based on user selections. Does this go against how meteor is designed? 
I've tried several approaches with no success. It seems I can't create new the collections after the server init?

I understand I can publish a meteor collection but I can't seem to call new Meteor.Collection(child_id) to make available for query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not how you use databases. You need one `Child` collection, and differentiate between several children with a dedicated field - for example `parendId`.